# How do you use flutter_qr_scan to get multiple QR codes

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to learn Flutter and am trying to use the library flutter_qr_scan to get a list of qr codes from a picture.  I followed the tutorial from https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_qr_reader but it only seems to get whatever qr code it finds first (only one).  How do I use that library (or some other library) to get multiple qr codes from an already taken picture?

```
            TextButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              var image =
              await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
              if (image == null) return;
              final rest = await FlutterQrReader.imgScan(File(image.path));
              setState(() {
                data = rest;
              });
            },
            child: Text("Identify Pictures")),
```